# durable-rules loading ruleset from json file

Tags: python, rule-engine, durable-rules

I came across durable-rules (python) https://github.com/jruizgit/rules rule engine framework.

I manage to write a dataset defined in Python code into a JSON file but cannot read it and execute it.

Is it possible, and does anyone have an example of how to load a dataset from a JSON file and use/execute it in the Python code?

Comment: Do you just need to open a json file stored locally? Then this should work: `import json; with open("json_filename.json") as f: json_data = json.load(f)`

Comment: Not exactly, I need to  load and use ruleset stored in JSON fille using durable-rules library